# escape character & stopping parsing

Tags: iphone, encoding, nsstring, decoding

I am trying to parse some data using nsxmlparser, whenever there is a &(ampersand) present in the text being received it just stops reading the parsed data. How can I read & normally, similar to other normal characters.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: In XML, & is *not* a normal character. It is a reserved character used to prefix entities.

Comment: is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Can’t you have your XML provider generate valid XML?

Comment: no it is not possible as i am reading the records from database and it is added by user itself. He may add anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the solution so i had to replace the & with some characters in backend and then again replace it in iphone while using it

Answer (score 1):

A lone ampersand in an XML document is not valid except in a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp). You can either have your XML provider provide valid XML by either:

1. Using the `&amp;` character entity where you want ampersands.
2. Putting text containing ampersands into a CDATA section.